# Wrapper Use Strings to Numeric?

Tags: java

```
Byte.parseByte(string)
new Byte(string).byteValue()
```

Please explain 2nd line how it is different from line 1.

Comment: Second line creates a `Byte` object, first line doesn't.

Comment: Second line uses a [constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Byte.html#%3Cinit%3E(java.lang.String)) that has been **deprecated** since Java 9, first line doesn't use deprecated code.

Comment: Both lines internally calls `Byte.parseByte(string, 10)`, but second line is more cumbersome.

Answer (score 0):

parseByte method returns a byte value which is a primitive type. Here is the code for this method:

```
public static byte parseByte(String s) throws NumberFormatException {
        return parseByte(s, 10);
    }
```

byteValue also returns a byte value but that byte value is actually a property of the Byte object that has been created. Look at the source code below where Byte object contains a property of byte type.

```
public Byte(String s) throws NumberFormatException {
    this.value = parseByte(s, 10);
}


public byte byteValue() {
        return value;
    }
```

Comment: The point is to show that Byte class contains the property. I am not sure how much well versed is the person who asked the question. Hence, tried to clarified.